# Value Error when using conditional on groupedby dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
avgTop5 =  df[df.groupby(['batter', 'game_date'])['launch_speed'] >= df.groupby(['batter', 'game_date'])['launch_speed'].quantile(.95)].mean()
```

This code returns the error below

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3695,) (3695,2)

The 'batter' column is a unique id number, 'game_date' is one of four years, so I want the average of the 'launch_speed' column for each player, for each year. But the average needs to be of the 'launch_speed' column only for values greater than or equal to the 95th percentile of the 'launch_speed' column for that player for that year. New to pandas

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html

If I understood correctly, then

```
df[df.groupby(['batter', 'game_date'])['launch_speed'].mean() >= df.groupby(['batter', 'game_date'])['launch_speed'].quantile(.95)]
```